# Handle the case where issuer is the Organisation Authorization

Tags: node.js, okta

I am using Open ID Connect (OIDC) to authenticate users into a web application and Okta org as an authorization server, where issuer is https://{subdomain}.okta.com.

And I am facing an issue which has already been registered as a bug and an Merge Request has already been registered on [Okta-Oidc-js](https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js)

[HERE](https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js/pull/708) and [HERE](https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js/pull/978)

This is a Node Library and the same library is in [Golang](https://github.com/okta/okta-jwt-verifier-golang) as well and it does not have any issue's as such.

I have an application that going to be on Production in upcoming months and I don't know, when these MR's will get merged. What are the alternative ways to tackle this case?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a custom authorization server where the issuer is different?

Comment: Hey @PruthviRajNadimpalli Well as you see, when I am using developer accounts of Okta where issuer is ```/oauth2/default```,   for non-production environment, I didn't faced this issue.  But for Org Authorization Server I did. Anyway, I didn't tried with custom authorization server. Could you be more descriptive on or share what are the pros and cons of creating custom authorization server? Maybe it could help me. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Hi @Dolly, if you are trying to use verify a token issued by Org Authorization server, it won't work as Okta doesn't expose keys for that authorization server. More differences can be found here: https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/Difference-Between-Okta-as-An-Authorization-Server-vs-Custom-Authorization-Server?language=en_US